# WebLogic Server firewall - Jboss Server (Jasper Server)

Tags: jboss7.x, firewall, oracle-adf, jasperserver, weblogic11g

Environment :

1. ADF application running on WebLogic Server 11gR1 - JDeveloer 11.1.1.7
2. We are doing report generation using Jasper Server deployed on JbossServer. Templates (i.e .JRXML) is present in Jasper Server

Application Requirement :

Report Generation for our ADF application running on WebLogic Server which is firewalled.

1. To fill the templates present in the jasperServer, dataMap has to be passed from weblogic Server to Jasper server as request through Web-Service.
2. Through URL fetching the generated report from JasperServer (i.e running on JBOSS)  into our ADF application I-Frames. As response passing weblogic server firewall.

Help :

How the request from the jasper server can be passed though our WebLogic Server Firewall into our application and reponse to vice versa..

Oracle EM - how can it help here. Is there any other solutions Please suggest...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Weblogic server is an application server, not an OS. So it doesn't have any way to "firewall" anything. So either you meant something else by "firewalling", or its an just an operation system problem and you have to specify, which OS you are using.